# Microsoft form multiple choice with a maximum of 2 answers per choice

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-forms

I need to build a microsoft form using power automate. I have a field for first name, one for last name and one for departments which has multiple choices (the user can select a maximum of 2 from that list). if any of the fields from the multiple choice question was selected from a total of 2 users (2 times), that field should disappear from the multiple choice question.

Example:
first name: ...
last name: ...
question with multiple answers: 1-x, 2-y, 3-z, 4-v, 5-n

user 1:
first name: aaa
last name:bbb
question with multiple answers: 1-x, 3-z

user 2:
first name: ccc
last name: ddd
question with multiple answers: 3-z, 5-n

now, the answer 3-z was selected 2 times, so user 3 and the rest of them should not see the option 3-z, only the remaining ones. and that should be the flow until all the departments are filled.

Can you help please? I am new to power automate. Thank you!

Comment: Power Automate is a workflow engine. Did you mean PowerApps? Or are you using Microsoft Forms and you want to manipulate the choices for the form with Power Automate? There is no way to create Microsoft Forms dynamically with Power Automate. If you want to manipulate the available options based on what has already been selected, you won't be able to do that with Microsoft Forms. You may want to look into PowerApps instead.

Comment: Hello. I am using Microsoft forms and I want to manipulate with Power automate.

Comment: Yeah, well, that won't fly. As I said in my comment above, you can't generate Microsoft Forms options dynamically by using Power Automate. It is possible with PowerApps, though.